# ¿Como llamar estos datos dentro de un foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

Buenas lo que quiero lograr es que al precionar un boton se cree una nuevo input como en el siguente ejemplo.

[image: Aqui la función que tiene es simple que al presionar el botón esta crea dos nuevos campos.]

El codigo es este.

```
 <script>
  var table1_inputs=0; // Este es mi contador

function crearInput() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    var input2 = document.createElement("input");


    table1_inputs++; // incremento el contador

    input1.name = 'repuesto'+table1_inputs;
    input2.name = 'cantidad'+table1_inputs;

    var campo4 = document.createElement("input"); //Creamos el boton de borrar
    campo4.type = "button";
    campo4.value = "Borrar";
    campo4.onclick = function() {
      var fila = this.parentNode.parentNode; //Eliminamos fila
      var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]; //Eliminamos campo
      tbody.removeChild(fila); // Metodo
    }
    cell2.appendChild(input1);
    cell2.appendChild(input2);
    cell2.appendChild(campo4);
}

 </script>
```

Y donde recibe es un form dentro de un table.

```
<form name="formulario " class="mt-5" id="formulario" method="POST" >
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
    <tr>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
      <button class="btn btn-primary w-25" onclick="crearInput()" type="button">
           Añadir campos
        </button>
    </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

La cosa es que al mandar los datos a la siguiente página quiero recibirlas dentro de un array['Cualquier nombre'], para poder recibirla y llamarlas con el método de foreach y a la vez claro, poder insertarlas con este mismo método.

Y actualmente como recibo los datos son de 1 por 1 de la siguiente manera.

[image: Los resibo 1 por 1]

Estaría insertando uno por uno y no me convendría de esa manera. ya que puede ingresar infinitos input el cliente.

Lo que quiero lograr es que los datos que envió a la siguiente página, estén dentro de un foreach para poder recórrelos.

No sé, si esta sea la manera correcta, ya que este código lo copie de otro lado y lo edite y bueno por algo se empieza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia esto:

```
input1.name = 'repuesto'+table1_inputs;
input2.name = 'cantidad'+table1_inputs;
```

por esto:

```
input1.name = 'repuesto[]';
input2.name = 'cantidad[]';
```

para que tengan el mismo nombre y se envien en forma de array, que después puedes capturar en PHP mediante un:

```
$repuestos = $_POST['repuesto'];
$cantidades = $_POST['cantidad'];
```

para después leerlos de forma correcta mediante un bucle, como podría ser este:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($repuestos); $i++) {
  echo 'El repuesto '.$i.' denominado '.$repuestos[$i].' tiene '.$cantidades[$i].' unidades.';
}
```

A partir de aquí haz lo que debas con los datos.

Comment: Gracias @masterguru me sirvió, como siempre un crack.